# How do I determine the inductance of a circuit using Op-amps, Capacitors and Resistors?

Tags: capacitor, operational-amplifier, resistors, impedance, gyrator

I am trying to prove that the inductance of a given circuit (between the source A, and ground) (see image below) is equal to (R1*R2*R4*C)/R3.

Under the assumption that it is an ideal op-amp, I know that the input to each of the op-amps is equal to the input voltage (A), and that there is no current entering.

I've attempted nodal analysis, but my main issue is that I don't know the current leaving either of the op-amps, and I can't find any information regarding a circuit like this one on the Internet.

On top of that, I also cannot figure out how to tackle the capacitor, so any advice regarding that would also be greatly appreciated.

Finally, the circuit is supposed to result in being equivalent to an inductor, L = (R1*R2*R4*C)/R3 , and that is what is required to prove.

[image: Circuit in question]

Comment: Are the crossed wires in the middle connected? (the node between R2 and C)

Comment: Yes, they're connected, sorry for the lack of clarity there.

Comment: Your units [don't result in inductance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_%28unit%29#Definition).

Comment: We don't mind hand-drawn schematics, but to avoid confusion next time please put a dot on each node, even the T's.

Comment: where is the frequency dependent factor of s in your equation?

Comment: Your formula needs a \$j\omega\$ in the numerator

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's supposed to result in being equivalent to an inductor, L = (R1*R2*R3*C)/R4.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't believe there is one.

Comment: @TheResistance How could it get there though? I'm utterly clueless.

Comment: The impedance of the capacitor is not 1/C, but 1/(\$j\omega\$C).

Comment: @TheResistance, I think the OP meant to write *inductance* instead of impedance.  Also, I believe the denominator should be R3 instead of R4.

Comment: @Alfred: correct, R3 and R4 should be swapped in the formula

Comment: @user2222956: The awesome thing about physics is that if the units don't match then the calculation is wrong, even if the scalar value is correct.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, inductance has units of \$\dfrac{Vs}{A} \$ as does the product \$R^2C\$ so the formula \$\dfrac{R_1 R_2 R_4 C}{R_3}\$ does indeed have the units of inductance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know the current through R4:

\$i_4 = \dfrac{A}{R_4}\$

Thus, you know the current through R3:

\$i_3 = i_4 \$

Thus, you know the output voltage of the 2nd op-amp:

\$v_{O2} = i_4(R_4 + R_3) = A(1 + \dfrac{R_3}{R_4})\$

Thus, you know the voltage across R2:

\$v_{R2} = A - v_{O2} = -A\dfrac{R_3}{R_4} \$

Thus, you know the current through R2 which is identical to the current through the capacitor:

\$i_C = i_{R2} = -\dfrac{A}{R_2}\dfrac{R_3}{R_4}\$

Now recall:

\$i_C = C \dfrac{dv_C}{dt}\$

Can you take it from here?

---

> I can't find an error in my calcs, so I think I'm just
>   misinterpreting what Vs and Is actually are.

Switching to the phasor domain, we have:

\$I_c =  -\dfrac{A}{R_2}\dfrac{R_3}{R_4} = j \omega C V_c\$

or

\$V_c =  -\dfrac{A}{j \omega}\dfrac{R_3}{R_2R_4C}\$

Thus, the output voltage of the first op-amp is:

\$V_{o1} = A + V_c = A - \dfrac{A}{j \omega}\dfrac{R_3}{R_2R_4C}\$

And the voltage across R1 is:

\$V_{r1} = A - V_{o1} = \dfrac{A}{j \omega}\dfrac{R_3}{R_2R_4C}\$

Finally, the current through R1 is:

\$I_{r1} = \dfrac{V_{r1}}{R_1} = \dfrac{A}{j \omega}\dfrac{R_3}{R_1R_2R_4C} \$

But the source current is identical to \$I_{r1}\$, thus:

\$\dfrac{V_s}{I_s} = \dfrac{A}{I_{r1}} = j\omega \dfrac{R_1R_2R_4C}{R_3} = j \omega L_{eq} \$

Comment: I can understand all that you've done there, but unfortunately I can't really nail that last step (I think).

Should I rearrange to get:
C(dV_c/dt) = -(A*R_3)/(R_2*R_4)
dV_c/dt = -(A*R_3)/(R_2*R_4*C)
V_c = integral [-(A*R_3)/(R_2*R_4*C)] dt
V_c = -(A*R_3*t)/(R_2*R_4*C)

Which then leaves me with the voltage across the capacitor, and it varies with time.

So then, the current across R_1, i_1 = (A-V_c)/R_1
Solve all of that..

And then (I think) all currents and voltages are found.. Right?

Comment: Shoot, and I forgot to mention in the original question, it's supposed to result in being equivalent to an inductor, L = (R1*R2*R3*C)/R4 :/ probably an important information.

Comment: When I solve it, I get that the equivalent inductance is \$L_{eq}=\dfrac{R_1 R_2 R_4 C}{R_3}\$

Comment: @user2222956, switch to the phasor domain to make it easier:  \$I_c = j\omega C V_c\$.  Then the voltage across the capacitor is \$V_c = -\dfrac{A}{j\omega}\dfrac{R_3}{R_2 R_4 C}\$

Comment: Ok then, so I've got the voltages across all of the resistors and the capacitor, but I still can't figure out how to combine all of that information into finding that L_eq. Sorry to keep being a bother, but have you got any advice there?

Comment: @user2222956, if you know the voltage across the capacitor, it is an elementary step to find the voltage across R1.  Having found that, you now know the current through R1.  Having found that, you now know the current through the source providing the voltage *A*.  Now, you have the source voltage and the source current.  That's all you need to find the equivalent inductance seen by the source.  Recall, \$V_s = j\omega L_{eq}I_s \$

Comment: So;
Vs = source voltage = A, Is = source current (i through R1) = -(A*R3)/(j*w*R2*R4*C);
Leq = Vs/(j*w*Is);
But when I solve I get:
Leq = (C*R1*R2*R4)/(j*w*C*R2*R5+R4)
I can't find an error in my calcs, so I think I'm just misinterpreting what Vs and Is actually are.

Comment: @user2222956, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it all makes sense now. I truly appreciate the help.